# Print taxonomy term field in views-view.tpl.php

Tags: views, theming, entities, taxonomy-terms

Do you know if it's possible to print a taxonomy term field inside a views-view.tpl.php template in Drupal 7?

For example, you would do this:

```
<?php print render($content['field_example_field']); ?>
```

in node--content-type.tpl.php.

What would be the equivalent to get a specific taxonomy term field in views-view--name-of-view.tpl.php?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your responses, but I figured it out. The view I was targeting was a content view not a term view, didn't think it was possible to add a Taxonomy term field. So I thought I could add the term field in a template (hence the question I asked here) but I worked it out in Views instead:

Went to Relationship, added "Content: Taxonomy terms on node".
Selected the Vocabularies I wanted to add in relationship.
Then went to Fields, "Add" and selected "Taxonomy term: Example Field".

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, hope this helps someone else (spent many countless hours googling this).

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to create the *Row style* output template file for the view.

For ex: `views-view-fields--your_view_name--block.tpl.php`.

In this file you get the *row array* and then you can print your field like:

```
$row->field_example_field[0]['raw']['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

In your *views template* file just add this line of code;

```
print render($fields['term_node_tid']->content);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to do the following;

*First:* ( on node page )

```
print_r($row);
exit;
```

You can see the list.

Now your can  print this as;

```
$row->field_example_field[0]['raw']['value']
```

And you get the value.